# How do you make a Sphinx doc with one .py file that has only functions?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

How do I make a Sphinx doc with one .py file that has only functions?

I have a .py file with multiple functions that have docstrings in them already but don't want to make a `:function:: console.someFunction` for all the functions. Is there a smarter or better way to iterate through all the functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, what you need is [autodoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html). Don't forget to add sphinx.ext.autodoc to conf.py.

Set up your sphinx docs as usual and in your .rst file have something along the lines of:

```
.. automodule:: myfile
   :members:
```